# Ruby on Rails and Datatables.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Pretty new to the RoR environment and have been trying to incorporate datatables.net into my project located at [here](https://datatables.net/manual/installation)

I know where to add the css along with the cdn which is the route I'm taking but the last step for 'Initialising DataTables' and the javascript? that is has there, where would this go in ruby on rails?  Spent a lot of time searching google for the answer to get a variety of solutions that didn't work and figured it was time to ask the wonderful experts here.

Comment: See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmXF0JfNDOE and also here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BElkjyZGvo (videos explaining how it's done). Code samples also provided. If you have large data sets then you will need to do server side pagination. In my opinion, it's not easy to get it set up, especially with turbolinks on.

Comment: I appreciate the videos but had seen those too prior to posting here.  Followed them both to the 'T' on a brand new rails app and for some reason, it just never works.  Good point on the server side pagination.  I'd like to get to there at some point but even getting the very basic to work is nerve racking.  Am running rails 5.1.7.  Is the turbolinks on a possible cause why it isn't working?

Comment: I don't know why it is not working on your project, but it's definitely not easy to get it working, that is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem.  Was a simple issue where the scripts where in the body and fixing them into the head section corrected the whole thing.